# Why Query taking much time to give result in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A(pid,pname,address), B(bid,baid,pid,details).
A has pid as primary key.and bid in B is primary key.
I ran query below.

```
select * from A a,B b where a.pid=b.pid and b.pid=100.
```

But this query taking much time to give data, and if i do small change in that query like below

```
select * from A a,B b where a.pid=b.pid and a.pid=100.
```

It gives me result fast.
I want to know the reason, why the first query taking time, not second query.

Comment: The primary key in b is bid or pid?

Comment: You have index on table a? and not in table b? .. or the number of row of the table a is small the in table b ?

Comment: As mentioned in the question  A has Primary key on PID so UNIQUE Index is created which helps in Searching. Whereas B doesnt have any indexes on bid (assuming).

Comment: Your where condition is more selective in table `A` than in table `B`. The db has no way of knowing about that (without gathering statistics). In case of very noticeable differences check whether `A.pid`, `B.pid` have an index.

Comment: A has more no of rows than B. and i didnt use any indexes on any table

Comment: Is it because we are using primary key in where clause?please confirm

Comment: Primary key fields are indexed by default.

Comment: is there any difference in datatype of pid in this two table ??

Comment: don't use antique syntax, avoid commas between tables in the from clause: `select * from A a INNER JOIN B b ON a.pid=b.pid WHERE a.pid=100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, pid is primary key in A. This means that a unique index will be created implicitly. This will reduce your search time. 
However, in case of B, pid is not a primary key. Hence, it takes time to show result.
Similarly, if you search with b.bid, your search time will be less.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that both tables have PID as PK. If this is so, the most logical explanation is that A has far less rows than B. Do a simple test:

```
select * from A a Right outer join B b on a.pid=b.pid where a.pid=100
```

This should slow down your query the way it does in your 1st example, as the query will try to retrieve all records from B.